# laravel eloquent relationship hasmany query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i am trying to implement a *sql* query

```
select * from user,comments where comments.user_id= user.id
```

so i create a `getcomments` method on my user model with following code

```
public function comments(){return $this->hasMany('Comments')}
```

and now am accessing the data by

```
$data = User::find(1)->comments;
```

but it gave me the data only from comments table (not user and comments )
how can i do this

Answer (score 5):

The Eloquent ORM follows the Active Record pattern. It is a slightly different way to think about modeling and interacting with your data when you come from writing pure sql statements.

Setting up the comments relationship is a good step. Now you need to think about how you interact with your data.

You can get all the information with the following statement:

```
$user = User::with('comments')->find(1);
```

With this statement, all of the user information is loaded into the `$user` object, and all of the comment information is loaded into the `$user->comments` Collection attribute. This information can be accessed like so:

```
// get the info
$user = User::with('comments')->find(1);

// display some user info
echo $user->first_name;
echo $user->last_name;

// loop through the comment Collection
foreach($user->comments as $comment) {
    // display some comment info
    echo $comment->text;
}
```

The `with('comments')` section tells the query to eager load all the comments for the returned users (in this case, just the one with id 1). If you didn't eager load them, they would be lazy loaded automatically when you try to access them. The above code would work exactly the same without the `with('comments')`. Eager loading becomes more important when your loading multiple parent records, though, instead of just one, as it solves the N+1 problem. You can read about [eager loading here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

**Caution (the reason I added a new answer):**

`User::find(1)->with('comments')->get();`, as otherwise suggested, is not going to provide the information you're looking for. This will actually end up returning all your users with their comments eager loaded. Here is why:

First, `User::find(1)` is going to return the one user with an id of 1, which is good. However, it then calls `with('comments')` on this model, which actually creates a new query builder instance for the users table. Finally, it calls `get()` on this new query builder instance, and since it doesn't have any constraints on it, it will return all the users in the table, with all the comments attached to those users eager loaded.

Answer (score 1):

First find a user. Then access all user data, and all comments of user.

```
$data = User::find(1);
//or you can use eager loading for more performance. thanks for @Özgür Adem Işıklı
$data = User::with('comments')->find(1);

//access user data
$data->id;
$data->email; //etc.

//user's comments:
foreach($data->comments as $comment) {
    //access comment detail
    $comment->id;
    $comment->title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching just comments of the user which you select by id. You should this;

```
User::find(1)->with('comments')->get();
```

Comment: Why it should work without eager loading? Can you give me more detail?

Comment: Eager loading is only a performance solution. It load all comments when you find user. If you don't use eager loading, the comments will be load when You type: $data->comments. Your solution is fine, but it should work without eager loading.

Comment: Actually you right but I think that if you write code without eager loading, the project will have lost a little bit performance. Because the project have to be develop over and over again. You can just fetch the comments today but tomorrow there will be another requests. And some of developers can use your methods in a view. If the developer is careful, it is ok. If he/she is not, there will be a performance issue, I think.

Comment: Please check my answer for information on your proposed solution.