# Laravel Eloquent query behaving strangely

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a very simple Eloquent query as follows

```
$sequent = EmailSequence::select('subject_line','message_body')->where('id',$id)->first();
```

If I then `dd($sequent)` I get the following with one row from the database as expected.

```
EmailSequence {#492 ▼
  #table: "email_sequence"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  ...
  #attributes: array:2 [▼
    "subject_line" => "Re: Email Sequence Test"
    "message_body" => "<p>Hi paul testing 2</p>"
  ]
  #original: array:2 [▶]
```

This is what I would expect, but if instead I do `dd($sequent->all())`  It is giving a **collection** of all the rows in the database, even though the `id` and everything else is different.

```
Collection {#490 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => EmailSequence {#478 ▶}
    1 => EmailSequence {#488 ▶}
    2 => EmailSequence {#486 ▶}
  ]
}
```

What have I done here? Why does Eloquent return all the rows?

Edit.  Ok I just realized that I don't need to use the method `first()` since the id is unique.   Using  `get()`  instead only returns the single row correctly.  So why is the `first()` method working this way in this case?

Comment: And this may be personal preference, but when working with a model, I always select the entire model, not only select attributes. If I only want specific attributes, I would use the `DB` query builder instead to retrieve a `stdClass` object.

Comment: @fubar  I understand that.  Then why am I getting a collection that contains 100% of the rows in the database?

Comment: I don't know. I've not seen that before. If you dump the raw SQL query, what does it show?

Comment: @fubar  weird  the raw query, using `toSgl()` method is `select * from email_sequence`  Which explains the results but still not why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get()` will always return a `Collection` containing the results. Even if there is only one result, it will be in a `Collection`.

`first()` calls `get()`, but then returns the first item from the resulting `Collection`. When you know your query conditions will result in one record, or you only care about the first record in the result, `first()` is what you want to use.

When searching by the primary key, it is customary to use the `find($id)` method. This is a shortcut for `where('id', $id)->first()`. So, your original statement could be rewritten as

```
$sequent = EmailSequence::select('subject_line','message_body')->find($id);
```

Your issue with the use of `all()` is due to a misunderstanding of the ActiveRecord pattern implemented by Eloquent. Every model instance has all the functions used to query the database and retrieve model instances. So, when you do `$sequent->all()`, what's really happening is that a new query is started, and it returns all the records in the entire table. In this case, `$sequent->all()` is the same as `EmailSequence::all()`.

You can also read my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040112/laravel-5-select-only-relationship-data-on-hasmany-relationship/36049097#36049097) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628528/laravel-eloquent-relationship-hasmany-query/34629691#34629691) for supplemental information.

Comment: So it is really executing two queries then.  This makes sense.  Thanks for the tip on using `find()` instead. I see there is a `findOrFail` method as well.  I am fairly new to Laravel  and appreciate the documentation,  but it does not seem like there is a quick reference of the methods available for queries anywhere.  Do you know where I might find such a thing? I did find the list for methods available for working with collections.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#available-methods

Comment: @skribe Someone may have created one somewhere, but not that I know of. Best place to start is the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-models). There is also the [api documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html), but I find it much more helpful just to dive into the source code.

Answer (score 2):

**get()** Eloquent Builder function   Executes the query as a "select" statement.

**first()** Eloquent Builder function is used to fetch first models by its / primary key (NOT LIKE SELECT* like `get()` does)

So when you do `dd($sequent->all())`

**all()** Eloquent Model method is a static method that creates the query and calls `get()` thats why you cant do `get()->all(); or all()->get()` you are basically calling get() under the hood therfore it executes a `select *` statment and you get a collection back!